# handling a click of Search suggestions (ContentProvider)

Tags: android, search, android-contentprovider

I'm using a content provider for search suggestions but I have a problem for handling a suggestion click. I explain the search works good but when I click in suggestion I go to the search activity but there isn't anything. My code for searching :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
    DataBaseUtil.startDataBase(getApplicationContext());

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        Cursor cursorAdapter = GetListResult(query);

        if (cursorAdapter != null) {
            cursorAdapter.moveToFirst();
        }
        startManagingCursor(cursorAdapter);
        String[] from = new String[] { SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1,
                BaseColumns._ID, SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
                "project_id" };
        int[] displayViews = new int[] { R.id.row_image, R.id.name_entry,
                R.id.name_id, R.id.name_descrption };

        final SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.layout_row, cursorAdapter, from,
                displayViews);

        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listAdapter.getItem(position);
                String i = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("project_id")));

                Intent intent = new Intent(ItemIntent.this,
                        AcceuilProjet.class);
                intent.putExtra("folderId", "0");

                intent.putExtra("projectName", " ");
                intent.putExtra("projectId", Long.valueOf(i));

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and this is my provider

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    String[] columns = new String[] {
              BaseColumns._ID,
          ProjectPersistence.KEY_WORD,
          ProjectPersistence.KEY_DEFINITION,
           /* SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
                            (only if you want to refresh shortcuts) */
              SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

    Cursor rtnCursor = null;
    Cursor rtnCursorProject = null;

//  Cursor rtnCursorMessage = null;
    String word = uri.getLastPathSegment();

    Log.d(TAG, " Search Provider query, word: " + word);

    if (!word.equals(SEARCH_QUERY)) {
        try {
            rtnCursorProject = ProjectPersistence.fetchProjectCursor(word);

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        rtnCursor = getMatrixCursor(rtnCursorProject);


    } else if (word.equals(SEARCH_QUERY_VIEW)) {
        // Handle a suggestions click (because the suggestions all use
        // ACTION_VIEW)
        try {
            rtnCursorProject = ProjectPersistence.fetchProjectCursor(word);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "anything", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Provider", "this is a item click");
    }

    return rtnCursor;
}
```

Please help me if you can

Comment: If you click back once, you should see the screen that details the selected item. What has happened is that the searchactivity is ontop of the activity display stack. you need to be able to close the search activity from code when a search suggestion is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                // handles a click on a search suggestion; launches activity to show word
                Intent intentShowLocal = new Intent(this, DetailsLocalActivity.class);
                intentShowLocal.setData(intent.getData());
                startActivity(intentShowLocal);
            }
```